# C MACRO to compare function names against predefined list of names

Tags: c, visual-studio, macros, precompile

I have some functions I'm hooking on windows (around 200), and I want to add some generic functionality to all of them. Based on a flag I'm giving my application, to either hook or not to hook some predefined functions.

What I had in mind would be something like this:

```
#define SHOULD_CHECK_STOP_MONITOR           (1 == Configuration.dwShouldMonitor)
#define MY_CHECK_MACRO(f) (if(SHOULD_CHECK_STOP_MONITOR && /* What do I do here? */))

void MyHookedFunctionName_A(...)
{
    if(!MY_CHECK_MACRO(__FUNCTION__))
        goto lbl_Cleanup;

    /* rest of code logic */

lbl_Cleanup:
    return ...;
}

void MyHookedFunctionName_B(...)
{
    if(!MY_CHECK_MACRO(__FUNCTION__))
        goto lbl_Cleanup;

    /* rest of code logic */

lbl_Cleanup:
    return ...;
}
```

The result I want to achieve is a precompiled logic, not to be executed on dynamic runtime, but on compilation. where if `1 == Configuration.dwShouldMonitor` is configured to be `True`, it will check the rest of the logic, where I would have some sort of predefined list of function names `["MyHookedFunctionName_A", "MyHookedFunctionName_C", "MyHookedFunctionName_D"]` and the Macro would know whether to return `False` or `True` based on function name. So in this example, `MyHookedFunctionName_B` would execute, while `MyHookedFunctionName_A` would not due to the predefined list on compilation.

Is something like that even possible? for a "Sophisticated" logic based on function name and compare it to predefined strings function names?

**edit 2019.09.15**:
I'm adding here what I'd like the result to be after precompilation logic

```
void MyHookedFunctionName_A(...)
{
    if(!(1 == Configuration.dwShouldMonitor && False))
        goto lbl_Cleanup;
...
}

void MyHookedFunctionName_B(...)
{
    if(!(1 == Configuration.dwShouldMonitor && True))
        goto lbl_Cleanup;
...
}
```

Where `True` or `False` were generated at compile time based on the function string names

Comment: I don't think it's possible with a macro. If it was C++, you could use a `constexpr` function...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , Is there no alternative equivalent in C? The only option I have is to execute this logic inside every function in runtime?

Comment: I can't think of any, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The result of a macro invocation is a text, generally that of a C or C++ program. It is not at all clear what kind of text you want to be generated. Can you post some text that you want to be generated when the flag is set, and some text you want to be generated from the same source when the flag is not set? You don't have to post the source before preprocessing. Just what you want to see after preprocessing.

Comment: hey @n.m., I've added the result I'm expecting, based on the function string names, I want it to conveniently create `True` or `False` statements which I control easily for all of my functions, without the need for this logic to be executed dynamically

Comment: I found this article on GNU's website.  They are giving an example of basiclly the same thing you aim to achieve.  Converting a macro argument to a character constant, so it can be evaluated.  It looks like it can be done, but not at compile time. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html#Stringizing

Answer (score 1):

Many compilers should be able to optimise your "runtime" check away completely.

Here is a simple program to illustrate the point.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static const char* func_list[] = { "foo", "bar" };

static inline int is_in_list(const char* f) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(func_list)/sizeof(func_list[0]); ++i)
        if (strcmp(f, func_list[i]) == 0)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}

#define HOOKME if (SHOULD_HOOK && is_in_list(__func__)) return;

void foo() {
    HOOKME;
    printf("foo\n");
}
void bar() {
    HOOKME;
    printf("bar\n");
}
void baz() {
    HOOKME;
    printf("baz\n");
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    bar();
    baz();
}
```

Compile it with -DSHOULD_HOOK=1 and -O2, and a good compiler probably will make `foo` and `bar` disappear.

```
foo:
  ret
bar:
  ret
.LC0:
  .string "baz"
baz:
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
  jmp puts
main:
  sub rsp, 8
  xor eax, eax
  call baz
  xor eax, eax
  add rsp, 8
  ret
```

Not all compilers are able to do that. Choose your tools wisely. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/47VRz7).

Comment: Seems like what I'm looking for, couldn't really get it to work though, any idea if it should work with `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015` compiler?

Comment: @0xAK This specific code does not work (i.e. MSC does not optimise it away).